# Asynchronous communication between threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

Backstage:
I'm practicing in Android development.
Trying to make an app that gets some data from remote http server.
Android system requires http requests to be done in separate threads.

So, I have a main thread, where some UI interactions happen, and the second thread (implementing Runnable interface), that makes http request.
There are two possible scenarios in second thread:

- everything goes right, and I'm getting a valid response
- some error occurred, and I want to notify my main thread about it

So the question:
What is the best practice to asynchronously communicate between threads?
I can't pause (sleep, wait) my main thread, because users should be able to interact with UI.

Thanks

**UPD**:
It is important that "Android" is just the place for testing.
I would like to achieve the result using "native" Java libraries/classes/...

Comment: If the main thread keeps going, just add a state to the runnable which you can scan from time to time? Observer pattern?

Comment: nablex,  do you mean that I should use timers to check some states periodicaly?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that. I do it usually like this (in MainActivity):

```
public void notification(final int title, final int message, final int duration) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, duration).show();
        }
    });
}
```

This example just notifies user but you may add or change run()'s content. 
**Edit**
According to [docs on runOnUiThread()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) it's a method intended to run pieces of code on UI-thread. It means that you may call it safely **from any thread**. The only thing you have to think about - is to have mainActivity reference in your thread.

**Edit2**
If you are going to do it in pure Java - use synchronized method to safely access object's content, like:

```
public class YourClassWithSychMethod {
    private int i;

    public synchronized void set(int val) {
        i=val;
    }

    public synchronized int get() {
        return i;
    }
}
```

This means that you may call these methods from any threads. It may be not a dedicated class, but any of your classes. 
So the **scenario** is following:
- Thread A calls `set()` and so notifies Thread B about some event
- Tread B in a thread-loop calls `get()` to check if required condition is met and reacts accordingly. Note that Thread B may use not thread-loop but any other loop, timer etc.

**Edit3**
You may also send a message to your UI-thread, like described in [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html) or for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705152/pass-a-message-from-thread-to-update-ui)

**P.S.** What about HTTP requests - I'm quite happy with [AsyncHttpClient](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) (or its counterpart SyncHttpClient if you have to move not only http-requests but **all** the related work into non-UI thread). This library takes care about a lot of trouble with threading and http communication handling

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain what is `runOnUiThread` method?

Comment: Ok, I've thought this is your own function. I've found it now. I've updated the question, so can you please advise something "androidless"?

Comment: As I understand synchronized method can stop thread if it tries to access this method while another thread is also accessing it. But my main thread must never be paused. Also: how will I understand that main thread should call this method? Timers?

Comment: Your thread will be stopped for microseconds to set a single int or boolean and you can't help it. See edit3 also:)

Comment: And since you mentioned Android - make a closer look at runOnUiThread() - very good convenience method the system gives you

Comment: I've mentioned also that I need to make it without Android libraries :)

Comment: Well, to be fully SYSTEM INDEPENDENT use Edit2 solution. I've added "usage scenario" there based on fact that main thread (there may be exceptions for single action non-UI apps) has a loop inside. Synchronized methods are easy, low-level and reliable. Hope it helps. If you want to implement it with Android and UI-thread - you should use message handling (Looper/Handler) or convenience method like runOnUiThread()

Answer (score -1):

Use YourThread.join() in Main Thread. This would stop Main Thread's working till you get response from YourThread. And you may decide a response to show to the user/ program flow depending upon response from YourThread.

Meanwhile while main Thread is working you show a toast to the user stating that HTTP information is being fetched.

Comment: I can't stop my main thread, because (as I've wrote) users should always be able to interact with UI.

Comment: 1st) that would not be for a long time. User may not feel the delay in response. 2nd) This method of showing toast is used almost as a standard in Android programming while fetching resources so don't worry.

Comment: It's not the matter of exact amount of time. UI thread should never be stopped. I've added an update to the question about Android.